# Using jquery to dynamically choose an audio file to load into HTML5 player

Tags: jquery, html5-audio

I'm trying to populate a HTML5 player in a modal via jquery. The goal is to play one of two mp3s based on whether you were invited to the website, or registered on your own. I have a hidden field that stores the src path and I want my jquery function to load the audio file based on that src. On page load, the audio file isn't loading into the player. Not sure what I'm missing, any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidModalMsg" runat="server" />

/*Unrelated code*/

<div class="audio" runat="server">
   <audio id="modalPlayer" onload="('#modalPlayer').src='';" controls="controls">
        <p>Your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
   </audio>
</div>
```

Jquery in header

```
$(function () {
    var audPlayer = $('#modalPlayer');
    audPlayer.src = $('#<%= hidModalMsg.ClientID%>').val();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

As audio source is different file for different browsers, changing audio src directly does not work. It has to be changed based on browser.

So set the src variable with appropriate value based on browser, see http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp for file support.

```
 var src = ".." // assuming your src has audio file value
 var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
 audio.setAttribute("src", src);
 audio.load();
```

With jQuery

```
 var src = $('#<%= hidModalMsg.ClientID%>').val();
 console.log(src);
 $('#audio_element').attr('src', src);
```

Comment: Both audio files are mp3. One or the other will play based on which path gets stored in the hidden field via C# code. The hidden field is getting populated correctly, but my jquery isn't loading the src path.

Comment: Nope, still nothing. :(

Comment: @Rex_C May I know the browser you are checking and what `console.log(src)` is logging.

Answer (score 0):

"Dynamically modifying a source element and its attribute when the element is already inserted in a video or audio element will have no effect. To change what is playing, either just use the src attribute on the media element directly, or call the load() method on the media element after manipulating the source elements."
Source: http://www.w3.org/

Did you tried audPlayer.play() after editing src?